# Split in SQL server query by >

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

---

I have Product table and has values for category path as "2210>2215>2219" and so on. Where 2210, 2215, 2219 are category Ids from Category table.

Few of the categories are inactive in database which is maintained at Category table.

To find products with inactive category in category path, I wish to write a query.

I wish to do something like this:

```
select  p.* from product p, category c
where c.categoryId in (split(p.categoryPath,'>'));
```

which should basically, split category path by '>' and return me few strings to be passed in 'in'.
Is there any way where I can split this and get separate strings to be passed in in clause for above query?

Comment: You forgot to ask the question !

Comment: Don't store data like that is the correct solution. Store relations, not paths. (SQL is designed for relations...)

Comment: @CoderofCode... lol, split function isnt available in sql-server, so I am looking for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to split string into rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670772/most-efficient-way-to-split-string-into-rows)

Comment: @jarlh, I wish I could... but this is done in a big framework where, such change would cause 1000 more changes in business logic.

Comment: @IvanSivak, not into rows exactly

Comment: @HarsH1610 I'm curious into what then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

create a function

```
 CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Sql query would be

```
select  p.* from product p, category c
where c.categoryId in (select value from fn_split(p.categoryPath,'>'));
```